# Records by month with year

Tags: sql

I need Following Output

### (Month)Year --- Items

---

2. (11)2012  -----        100
3. (12)2012   -----       200
4. (01)2013   -----       100
5. (02)2013    -----      400
6. (03)2013   -----       250

Comment: Please share you table's structure. Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming RDBMS is `mysql`;
Assuming table structure as below;

```
create table tbl(date_clm date, item int);
```

query:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date_clm, '(%m)%Y') as Month_Year, sum(item) as items 
from tbl 
group by Month_Year;
```

Comment: One small potential problem with your approach is that it won't be trivial to order the output by sorting on the string value. But I recognize it's hard to do much with the info we've been given.